# Physics/chemistry understanding of PMOS and NMOS to form CMOS

Tags: transistors, physics, semiconductors

Can anyone provide me explanations or links that provide a clear explanation of what atoms/molecules are in p-type and n-type (PMOS/NMOS) and how they interact to create actions?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia doesn't do a bad job of explaining the basic process of doping a semiconductor to form a P/N type material. The [Doping Semiconductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_%28semiconductor%29) page particularly. For silicon, generally Boron is used to dope for P-type, and Phosphorus is used to create N-type.

Essentially, doping creates either extra electrons (N-type) or holes (P-type) and produces a material that has a "useful" function. Semiconductors on their own aren't of much use until you add these impurities.

Comment: "Wiki" as in "Wikipedia"?

Comment: Yep, I'll correct it.